# Google Plugin for Eclipse Mars: No option to "deploy to AppEngine"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I installed Eclipse Mars and the Google Plugin for Eclipse, as well as Google App Engine Java SDK from scratch. The project-specific settings point to Java 1.7.

I can run Web Applications just fine locally, but when I right-click on the project, there is no option to "Deploy to AppEngine" under the "Google" options.

Re-installing the plugin did not fix the problem...

Comment: Is there any error, warning or something else ? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The "Deploy to App Engine" option is located in the GDT pulldown menu (the 'g') in the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks! It used to be that you can deploy via right-click on the project... obviously no longer the case. But deploying via the 'g' button works now.